# I am not able to see the website title in Safari on macOS

Tags: macos, safari, google-chrome

I open a website in Safari by entering the website address in the address bar. But I am not able to see the title of the website.

When I open the same website in Google Chrome I can see the title for the website such as "Online Shopping site" in the title bar. But I want to use Safari because I think my MacBooks battery drain very quickly when I am using Google Chrome.

Is there not way to see website title in Safari like in Google Chrome?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Safari displays the website title in what it calls the Tab Bar. You apparently have the Tab Bar set to hidden.

To show the Tab Bar, open Safari on your computer, select View → Show Tab Bar in the Safari menu and the Tab Bar should now appear.

[image: Safari View Menu]

Selecting Show Tab Bar would enable Safari to always display the Tab Bar. It would work even after you quit and relaunch Safari.

You should now be able to see the website title easily.

Comment: Thank you. it is working. Thank you for sharing image of menu, that made it easy.